# String arithmetic decrement in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a field X in my database which contains text values. My values are all ascii (between 0-255 ascii code), I would like to decrement all my values.
If we have for instance '1' as the text, it should be '0' instead. At first I wanted to use the function ASCII and CHAR but they are not available in sqlite. Any tips ?

Comment: Use a number. (This sounds glib, but if you want to treat a column as a number, why not have it be a number?)

Comment: The database already exists and I can't modify it.

Comment: Is this something you must do directly in sqlite3 or do you have a language available? I'm not sure if sqlite3 has many (any?) conversion functions built-in.

Comment: Yes I can use a php script, so you would suggest to build my own php function ?

Comment: Not sure what choice you have; a quick scan of sqlite3 functions didn't show anything, but I'm also not overly-familiar with sqlite3 :/

Comment: If the SQLite database backs an app, what is the app written in? A variety of SQLite providers allow you to create custom functions in your front-end language, which would let you do what you wish to do here.

Comment: `My values are all ascii (between 0-255 ascii code)` What would you do if the starting value = ASCII 0?

Comment: Does this text field have length 1 or can the strings be longer?

Comment: I should have been more precise : the string is one character long and the sqlite is on my computer. This operation should be done only once and it doesn't matter how long it takes : so I did a script in php (after installing a php server on my computer) that select each row then decrement the value in php and then updates it with a sql statement. And for the ascii code 0, it didn't actually happen but 255 would be the value to put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are all a single character, you can use a table of replacement values; here's a partial example:

```
sqlite> create table m1 (c,p);
sqlite> insert into m1 values ('b','a');
sqlite> insert into m1 values ('c','b');
sqlite> insert into m1 values ('d','c');
sqlite> create table tst (x);
sqlite> insert into tst values ('c');
sqlite> insert into tst values ('c');
sqlite> insert into tst values ('d');
sqlite> insert into tst values ('d');
sqlite> select * from tst;
c
c
d
d
sqlite> update tst set x = (select p from m1 where c = x);
sqlite> select * from tst;
b
b
c
c
sqlite>
```

You'd have to flesh out the m1 table for all possible values.

Comment: +1 for implementing a discrete function as a table lookup and for mentioning the caveat.

Comment: Nice solution. My solution was finally just to use php and it made the trick but if you don't have any access to an external language, your solution is the way to go.